# Limit $(-1)^n/n!$ convergence

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

I need to prove that the following sequence is convergent, and then to compute the limit when $n\to\infty$.

$$b_n = {\frac{(-1)^n}{n!}}$$

I was thinking of using sandwich rule in the following way:

$$0\leq \bigg|\frac{(-1)^n}{n!}\bigg|\leq \frac1{n!}$$

As $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1{n!}=0$, I can conclude $\lim_{n\to\infty}b_n=0$.

I am not sure if I am assuming something not correct, but this exercise was on an exam and my resolution seems too easy for the points it was worth in the exam. Many thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Your solution is absolutely correct

Comment: Why did you introduce absolute values? You could simply use the fact that$$-\frac1{n!}\leqslant\frac{(-1)^n}{n!}\leqslant\frac1{n!}.$$

Comment: If "solution seems too easy for the points it was worth in the exam", I suspect you were not asked for the convergence and limit of the *sequence* $(b_n)$, but for the convergence and sum of the *series* $\sum{n=0}^\infty b_n.$

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos that is the exact same thing as the inequality with absolute values

Comment: @FShrike From $0\leqslant\left|\frac{(-1)^n}{n!}\right|\leqslant\frac1{n!}$, what you can deduce directly is that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\left|\frac{(-1)^n}{n!}\right|=0$. You still need to deduce from that that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{n!}=0$. That's easy, of course, but it's an extra step nevertheless.

Comment: @AnneBauval In the exam it only asks for the convergence and limit of the sequence, I was sure of my answer, but it was 2.5 points (over 10) of the exam. To put into context, othe problem (of 2.5 points too) was to represent a curve given in polar coordinates  (cardioid) and to compute its length. It seems a bit unbalanced. In any case, many thanks for your comments!

Comment: Moreover, it was 1 point to prove it is convergent and 1.5 points to compute the limit. I don't understand how both things (convergence and limit) can be evaluated separately...  (sorry for insisting, but I was very confused)

Comment: I do want to add to the suspicion that the problem was asking (at least was _meant_ to ask) to check convergence and calculate the limit of the _series_ $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{n!}$. For _that_, you would need to recall that $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n!}=e^x$ and the series on the left is convergent for all $x\in\mathbb C$. So the sum would be $e^{-1}$. It may be that the problem was given with the wording "sequence" by mistake and then they had to accept the "easy" solutions. Just speculating.